# Installation of Clingo on a Mac

Tags: macos, installation, clingo

I am trying to install Clingo on my Mac (macOS Mojave -- 10.14.3).

I have downloaded the last version of Clingo (5.3.0) and unzipped it. If I open the Clingo file with the terminal it says:

```
Last login: Fri Mar  1 09:31:31 on ttys000
Mattias-MacBook-Pro:~ esther$ 
/Users/esther/Documents/clingop/clingo ; exit;
clingo version 5.3.0
Reading from stdin
```

I have also downloaded homebrew and Xcode.

I have .lp file (pippo.pl) that I would like to run. What should I do to run this file?

I tried in several ways from the Terminal, but nothing happens.

I have created an alias clingo="documents/clingop/clingo" and then from the directory of the pippo.pl file I wrote

`clingo pippo` , but the Terminal says: `-bash: documents/clingop/clingo: No such file or directory`

So it seams that somehow it cannot read the file clingo

Do you know how I could solve this? thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The important line is `Reading from stdin`.

You can call clingo so that it processes your file as follows:

`/Users/esther/Documents/clingop/clingo pippo.pl`

or if your shell is bash (or similar):

`cat pippo.pl |/Users/esther/Documents/clingop/clingo`

or

`/Users/esther/Documents/clingop/clingo <pippo.lp`